# Does the container and presentational patter is still a best practice with hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I recently learned hooks. In my previous company I've used the presentational/container pattern (with recompose).

However in the famous article from Dan Abramov, he points out that he has changed his mind regarding this pattern.

Still I've seen recent articles recommending the presentational/container pattern.

So, in this age of hooks, does this pattern is still considered a best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Hooks` are easy to use and introduced for performance optimization. We can achieve every scenario, that is possible with life cycle methods. Coming towards your question, presentational / container pattern is a way to structure things.

Developer's use different terms to make development easy and resuable. In the pattern, Presentational components are how things are displayed on the screen (Purely Designing stuff) while containers are components that communicate with `redux` or any third-party API to get data.

To just enhance the structure of the application and developer experience using presentational / container pattern is a good idea and mostly preferred by developers.